# C++ Read in file with only numbers (doubles)

Tags: c++, file, stream, double

I'm trying to read in a file that *should* contain only numbers in it. I can successfully read in the entire file if it meets that criteria, but if it so happened to have a letter in it, I need to return false with an error statement.

The problem is I'm finding it hard for my program to error when it finds this character. It can find it no problem, but when it does, it decides to just skip over it.

My code to read in the file and attempt to read in only numbers:

```
bool compute::Read (ifstream& stream) 
{
    double value;
    string line;
    int lineNumber = 1;

    if (stream)
    {
        while (getline(stream, line))
        {   
            lineNumber++;
            istringstream strStream(line);

            while (strStream >> value)
            {
                cout << value << endl;
            }

        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

The input file which I use for this is

```
70.5 61.2 A8 10.2
2
```

Notice that there is a non-number character in my input file. It should fail and return false at that point.

Currently, all it does is once it hits the "A", it simply returns to the next line, continuing the getline while loop.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Let's be clear. The file doesn't contain `doubles,` or if it does you should be reading it in binary. It contains *real numbers* in text format, which you need to *convert* to `double.`

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any instructions to stop and return false ...

Comment: @EJP It does contain doubles, they are represented as text.

Answer (score 1):

The stringstream *does* catch those errors, but you're doing nothing to stop the enclosing loop from continuing when an error is found. You need to tailor your main loop so that it stops when the stringstream finds an error, which you can't do if the stringstream is being reconstructed on each iteration. You should create a `for()` loop instead and construct the stringstream in the declaration part. And the condition to the loop should be "as long as the stringstream and `stream` do not catch an error". For example:

```
for (std::istringstream iss; iss && std::getline(stream, line);)
{
    iss.clear();
    iss.str(line);

    while (iss >> value)
    {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }
}
```

Futhermore, it doesn't look like you need to use `std::getline()` or `std::istringstream` if you just want to print each value. Just do:

```
while (stream >> value) {
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}
```

The above will stop when it finds an invalid character for a `double`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems as though the while loop in the first half of your comment does not ever enter, though. I tried using that and giving it a file with only numbers, and it just did not ever enter it. Any idea why that might be? I checked and it does enter the for loop, though.

Comment: @Sej If it's still not working, move the `iss.clear()` above the `iss.str()` line.

Answer (score 0):

You need the code to stop streaming but return false if it hasn't yet reached the end of the "input".

One way, possibly not the most efficient but still one way, to do that is parse a word at a time.

If you read first into a `std::string` and if it works (so the string is not empty) create an `istringstream` from that string, or reuse an existing one, and try streaming that into a `double` value.

If that fails, you have an invalid character.

Of course you can read a line at a time from the file, then split that into words, so that you can output a meaningful error message showing what line the bad text was found.

The issue of reading straight into doubles is that the stream will fail when it reaches end of file.

However it is possible to workaround that too because the reason for failing has an error status which you can check, i.e. you can check if it `eofbit` is set. Although the f in eofbit stands for "file" it applies to any stream not just files.

Although this method may sound better than reading words into a string first, I prefer that method in normal circumstances because you want to be able to report the error so you'll want to print in the error what was read.